# Can i use a jpeg image for launching Screen

Tags: iphone, launcher

i was currently in to an app development and i have added a launcher screen in JPEG format which is displayed both in simulator and device .. but does it create any problem with apple approval guidelines ?

Comment: Why not simply save it as png?

Answer (score 5):

Update for iOS 8+: you can now use [XIB-based launch assets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1), which is by far the best approach to reduce file size and re-use the same assets for multiple screens sizes.  Also, since XIBs support JPG assets, you can always embed JPGs onto XIB files now too!

---

The Apple documentation pre iOS 8 (now removed), explicitly stated that only PNG is allowed for the launch image:

**App Launch (Default) Images**

> Every app must provide at least one launch image. This image is
>   typically in a file named Default.png that displays your app’s initial
>   screen in a portrait orientation. However, you can also provide other
>   launch images to be used under different launch conditions. **All launch
>   images must be PNG** files and must reside in the top level of your
>   app’s bundle directory. (Avoid using interlaced PNGs.)

I can't speak to how accurate this document is, but it seems they *are* pretty specific on this point.

My advice: use 8-bit PNG's, and if your files are getting to big, simply don't include the @2x versions for the retina iPad. The 1x version upscales reasonably well on the retina iPad, and better than bloating your app by 5MB+

Comment: I've read that JPGs work. However, you'd need to sneak them past XCode which will currently complain. And you probably risk your app breaking with a future iOS update. Better bite the bullet and use png. I sure hope Apple will allow JPG soon but until then make do with 8 bit PNGs.

Comment: Obsolete quote. Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html

Comment: Looks like the documentation has been changed. You should be using XIB-based launch images for iOS 8+ now anyway, as the file sizes are far better (and you can embed JPGs inside the XIB if you need!).

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse you can use JPEG image in Launch screen or anywhere in project.NO it absolutely does not create any problems in approval process of Apple.So go ahead and code!

Answer (score 0):

Use a png if you can; not only is png artwork better visually, but iOS is optimised for png files.

While it is true Apple won't reject your app for using a jpeg, your users might.

Comment: LOL... Ever thought about the file format of a launch image you saw?

Comment: This is kind of ridiculous. A JPEG at full quality is indistinguishable from a PNG, whilst still being smaller. Obviously a low quality JPEG looks rubbish, but the quality used is up to the developer.

Comment: I said 'might' — and I definitely can tell the difference on a retina device. But why bother, since PNGs are crushed anyway?

Answer (score 0):

NO you should not use jpgs

Here are [apple recomendations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

**Note: For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended.
The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits (8 bits each for red, green, and blue), plus an 8-bit alpha channel.
You do not need to constrain your palette to web-safe colors. Although you can use alpha transparency in the icons you create for navigation bars, toolbars, and tab bars, do not use it in application icons.**

Answer (score 0):

You can only use PNG files for the launch images.  Here is the proof.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes , you can choose any one from JPEG/PNG.There is no guidelines from apple to choose type of image.

For more information you can follow apple [launch image guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5).

but I assume that PNGs are more preferable because Apple seems to use PNGs virtually everywhere in iPhone OS.

Comment: @Rafael Sanches, Do you have any proof for this comment.I am sure Apple prefers PNG but it is not that you must provide PNG.If you provides JPEG , also it will work but you have to compromise with the quality.

Comment: This Apple document explicitly states that only PNG is allowed for the launch image. See the other comments.